# Proving the inequality $2^{-1+\frac{1}{n}}\left(x+1\right)\leq\left(x^{n}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N} $ and $x>0$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Prove that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x>0$, 
>   $$2^{-1+\frac{1}{n}}\left(x+1\right)\leq\left(x^{n}+1\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

The last class was about Taylor polynomial of functions, so I thought this might give me a solutions, but looking at the derivatives the only think I could think would be useful is looking at the $n-1$th degree polynomial of

$$\frac{\left(x+1\right)^n}{2^{n-1}}-\left(x^{n}+1\right)$$

(Which I got by raising to the $n$th power)

Though this gave me the ugly expression (for some $c$ in $[0,x]$):

$$f\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}+\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}x+\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2^{n-1}2!}x^{2}+\dots+\frac{n\left(n-1\right)\cdots\left(3\right)}{2^{n-1}\left(n-2\right)!}x^{n-2}+\left(\frac{n!\left(c+1\right)}{2^{n-1}}-n!c\right)\frac{1}{\left(n-1\right)!}x^{n-1}$$

Which I have no idea how to "make negative". So I tried falling back to induction, but after the pretty obvious base case of $2$ I had no idea how to continue.

Any tips/hints on how to prove it?

Comment: Should that not read $$2^{1-n}(x+1)^n-(x^n+1)?$$

Comment: @Stromael, fixed, thanks...

Comment: Binomial theorem?

Comment: I tried using Binomial Theorem, It's how I solved the other side of the inequality, but with this side I had pretty much the same thing as with Taylor polinomial, which I had no idea how to proceed with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put $t=x-1$ and $d=x^n+1-2\bigg(\frac{x+1}{2}\bigg)^n$, you have

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
d &=& 1+(1+t)^n-2\bigg(1+\frac{t}{2}\bigg)^n \\
&=& 1+\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} t^j -\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} \frac{t^j}{2^{j-1}} \\
&=& 1+\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} \frac{2^{j-1}-1}{2^{j-1}}t^j \\
&=& \sum_{j=2}^n \binom{n}{j} \frac{2^{j-1}-1}{2^{j-1}}t^j 
\end{array}
$$

and all the terms in the last sum above are clearly positive (except possibly for $t^j$). This shows that $d\geq 0$ whenever $x\geq 1$.

Comment: We haven't really talked about properties of convex function, so I have no idea how to justify what you wrote, any other options?

Comment: @Nescio I replaced with my old proof with another that only uses the Newton binomial.

Comment: Well that does it...

Comment: @Nescio not quite, my proof only works for $x\geq 1$. Apologies for not noticing that the first time I wrote it

Answer (score 0):

This is the *power mean inequality*: the p-power mean of $a$ and $b$ is 
$$m_p(a,b)=\biggl(\frac{a^p+b^p}2\biggr)^{\!\tfrac1p}$$
and if $p\le q$, $m_p(a,b)\le m_q(a,b)$. Of course, $m_1$ is the usual arithmetic mean, and $m_{-1}$ is the harmonic mean.

Here you can rewrite the inequality as:
$$\frac{x+1}2\le\smash{\biggl(\frac{x^n+1}2\biggr)^{\!\tfrac1n}},\enspace \text{i. e.}\quad  m_1(x,1)\le m_n(x,1).$$